# Display php array in DataTable

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatables, echo

I wanted to echo php query variable into `datatable`, it works but `css` is `overflow` and everything went to white.
I used `datatable.net` library, it is not just for DataTable Library , the same happen for html Table too

MyQuery :

```
<?php 
    $log_query_array = array(
        "query" => "SELECT * FROM vn_log",
        "query_variables" => array()
    );

    $log_list = vn_db_query_select( $log_query_array );
?>
```

HTML and Echo :

```
<table class="vn_LogList">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ip</th>
        <th>referer</th>
        <th>useragent</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>datetime</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($log_list as $log) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $log["ip"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $log["referer"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $log["useragent"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $log["status"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $log["datetime"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

And here is Jquery :

```
$('.vn_loglist').DataTable({
   "bprocessing": true,
   "bserverSide": true,
});
```

It is like this:

[image: Image description]

But it should be like this:

[image: Image description]

Any Solution or Help ? or advice ?

Comment: Your CSS is not rendering. We need your css and html, not images.

Comment: @EternalHour i am using datatablelibrary

Comment: I said your css is not rendering. I see no css links there.

Comment: @EternalHour Imagine with no CSS ,even i use HTML Table it happens, even without Table Library , even without CSS